# Searching for an input keyword in all fields of an elasticsearch document using c# nest client

Tags: c#, .net, search, elasticsearch, nest

I have a nested elasticsearch document and I want to search within all the fields of that document i.e I want to search in both the top-level and the nested fields. My index name is `people` and my type name is `person`.
My documents look like this :

```
{
"id": 1,
"fname": "elizabeth",
"mname": "nicolas",
"lname": "thomas",
"houseno": "beijing",
"car": [
          {
             "carname": "audi",
             "carno": 4444,
             "color": "black"
          },
          {
             "carname": "mercedez",
             "carno": 5555,
             "color": "pink"
          }
      ]
}
```

Then i have the following query in `.net` which actually searches for an `user input keyword` in the elasticsearch documents. Basically, I want to search in each and every field of a document. And I use `inner_hits` in my query so that i can return only the matching nested document.
I have designed my query as :

```
var result = client.Search<person>
                (s => s
                .From(from)
                .Size(size)
                .Source(false)
                .Query(query => query.Filtered(filtered => filtered
                .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
                .Filter(f => f.Nested(nf => nf
                .InnerHits()
                .Path(p => p.car)
                .Query(qq => qq.Match(m => m.OnField(g =>  g.car.First().carname).Query(searchKeyword))))))));
```

And my corresponding JSON query which i use in the head plugin is :

```
POST-people/person/_search:
{
"_source":false,
"query": {
  "filtered": {
    "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
      "nested": {
      "path": "car",
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "car.carname": "searchKeyword"
        }
      }, 
      "inner_hits" : {}
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

But i wanted to search in all the fields(id,fname,mname,lname,houseno,carname,carno,color) and not just in a single field e.g. in carname as i have done in my above query.
Also, i want to do `partial searching` like `%xyz%`.
How can i do these ?
Can anyone help me modify this query so that i can use this single query to search within all the fields as well as do partial searching?
I'm new to elasticsearch as well as .net,so I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching ElasticSearch using NEST C# Client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581464/searching-elasticsearch-using-nest-c-sharp-client)

Comment: @Larry .. The page that you have mentioned just searches on all fields and has a simple search query. But i wanted to add the features i have mentioned in my query which is actually meant to search in nested documents(you can see my query written above).The problem is I'm unable to figure out how to integrate those into my Query.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I retract the "duplicate" vote. The link appears in the related questions anyway if someone is interrested.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using `Query` instead of `OnField` method?

I mean, having your query this way:

```
var result = client.Search<person>
            (s => s
            .From(from)
            .Size(size)
            .Source(false)
            .Query(query => query.Filtered(filtered => filtered
            .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
            .Filter(f => f.Nested(nf => nf
            .InnerHits()
            .Path(p => p.car)
            .Query(qq => qq.Match(m => m.Query(searchKeyword))))))));
```

Comment: @Mickey .. Thankx for your answer. I checked this out but it simply returns each and every document present in my table.